# rails webpacker react MissingEntryError

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, react-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1, webpacker

I'm trying to setup my new project with Rails 5.1 and Wepacker-react, but I get first error very quickly.
I have been created new component in **javascript/packs** 
The code is basic:

*javascript/packs/home.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Home = props => (
  <div>Hello {props.name}!</div>
)

Home.defaultProps = {
  name: ''
}

Home.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Home name="Daniel" />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

Im rendering this component in index view:

*index.html.erb*

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home' %>
```

But I got this error: 
[MissingEntryError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oen4J.png)

I would to add  that I had imported this component in app....js
What is missing?

Comment: It's going to look in your manifest.json file to determing what it can load with `javascript_pack_tag`. What does your manifest.json look like?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error where I was getting the same error message.

Another error message related to MissingEntryError was:

> Webpacker can't find react_file.js in
>   /home/.../Workspaces/my-app/public/packs/manifest.json

The manifest.json file had not been created.

The problem was solve after I added some missed NPM packages, such as Webpack-dev-server and @rails/webpacker. All those missed packages were part of node_modules folder. I just had to install them to solve the problem.